# Draw smoothly colored quad in OpenGL ES 1.0 on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to render a smoothly colored rectangle in OpenGL ES. Since one cannot directly draw a quad, I'm using two triangles. With a smooth shading, the result is as the picture from Lesson 5 here: [INsanity Design OpenGL ports](http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/).

Note the diagonal. The result is dependent on how the triangles make up the quad. I would like to have this result [here](http://www.naturewizard.com/tutorial0103.html) (scroll down to the bottom).

Is there a possibility to get a smoothly colored quad?